# How to add new EIP and how are they numbered?

Tags: eip

Hi I have a question to community. How do I add a new EIP? Also, how are the EIP numbers allocated?

Answer (score 3):

You should refer to [EIP-1](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1) to read the full process. The TL;DR is that you need to fork the EIPs repo, add your EIP that follows the [template](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/eip-X.md), and create a pull request to the master of the EIPs repo that adds your EIP as a draft. After that, you need to drum up discussion about your EIP by posting in some places to get feedback. After some discussion, you can put it in last call, and after 2 weeks in last call, it can be finalized. The process differs a bit for changes that require a fork, which you can read more about in EIP-1 linked above.

As for numbering, they're numbered usually based on PR number.